# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express project creation failed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Before I begin, I would like to note that I am running Windows XP SP3.

Recently, I noticed that my installation of MS Visual C++ 2008 Express would no longer create new projects, only open previously created ones. Please note that it has been able to create projects in weeks prior.

Rather than trying to find a solution for the 2008 version, I took the opportunity to upgrade to MS Visual C++ 2010 Express. After downloading and installing it, I encountered the same problem, only this time (will not create new projects), I noticed a message near the bottom of the window that read "Creating project '[project]'... project creation failed". I then uninstalled both versions (2010 and 2008), rebooted, reinstalled 2010, and... same problem.

I then followed [this](http://www.thedeveloperspoint.com/?p=44) tutorial, where I (re)registered VsWizard.dll, then modified the owners of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.10.0 and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VsWizard.WizCombo.9.0 to Administrators, and gave all users Full Control/Read permissions. This seems to be the solution that a number of other websites suggest, but it still did not help.

Thus, I am at a loss of where to go next. I, unfortunately, have no Restore Point to fall back on, so I need a different solution, if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you go (in the command prompt) to wherever the devenv.exe is located and run it with the command "devenv /ResetSkipPkgs" without quotes?

Comment: It seems that devenv is not on my machine. Should it be?

Comment: @C. Short: `devenv` **is** Visual Studio. You might have to `cd` to it's location in `Program Files` first.

Comment: I did. It should be in 'C:\{Visual Studio Install Dir}\Common7\IDE', right? 'devenv.exe' isn't in there and searching for it returns nothing. If it's not in that particular directory, where would it be?

Comment: "devenv.exe" is the Visual Studio IDE shell for the non-Express SKUs.  The Express SKUs use different program names, e.g. "VBExpress.exe" for Visual Basic Express.

Comment: Oh. Then would I run 'VCExpress.exe /ResetSkipPkgs' instead of 'devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs'?

Comment: I can't help you there, sorry; I've never used the Visual Studio Express SKUs.  @Bart?

Comment: @C. Short I am not a user of the express edition myself. So I'm not sure if devenv is available there. You could perhaps check what the command line switches are for vcexpress.exe.

Comment: No /ResetSkipPkgs, but there was a /ResetSettings switch, which I ran. This effectively did nothing, as this is a fresh install. Currently, I am out of time, but thanks for the help you provided.

Comment: It's not a language related question, removing c++ tag.

Comment: Do you install some programs in interval from last time you have succesfully created project in VS through first time you face project creation problem? Maybe it was Installshield Community edition?

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of issues and frustration with solving this "issue", nothing worked.
I changed my default ProgramFiles directory to my D drive as my C drive runs a SSD. By monitoring the visual studio process, I discovered that it was looking for MSBuild / Microsoft.Cpp on my D drive (not on my C drive, where my operating system is located). This was what caused the issue.